# dplyr default grouping option

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I'm a bit confused about the default grouping option in dplyr. I always assumed that without explicitly `group_by` any operations are rowwise. However, I have a data frame

```
data =  data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c(1,2,3,4))
```

and when I want to calculate the mean of each ROW

```
data = data.raw %>%
  mutate(data.average = mean(c(a,b),na.rm = T))
```

it returns the mean value of all the elements in `a` and `b`. It seems by doing `c()` all data are grouped in one group and mean performed on that. I wonder how it is possible to know how functions used within `mutate` etc. introduce grouping.

ps. I'm not looking for a solution for this specific problem, but asking for more generally how function calls affect grouping in `dplyr`.

Comment: The default operation is *no grouping*, meaning all rows at once. If you want individual rows, you need to use `%>% rowwise() %>%`. (An exception is if you use `purrr::map` or similar.)

Comment: As an example (I know you don't need this particular problem solved), you could do either `%>% mutate(avg = purrr::map2_dbl(a, b, ~ mean(c(.x,.y))))` or `%>% rowwise() %>% mutate(avg=mean(c(a,b)))`.

Comment: To clarify, no grouping means all data as one group or each row as one group?

Comment: "no grouping" means all data as one group. Perhaps it would help to think of `group_by` (and `rowwise`) as a way to shrink the amount of data for each call to `mutate` (and cousins).

Comment: I see. I thought the opposite.